# How to access nested schema column?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Kafka streaming source with JSONs, e.g. `{"type":"abc","1":"23.2"}`.

The query gives the following exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:  extraneous
input '.1' expecting {<EOF>, .......}
 == SQL == 
person.1
```

What is the correct syntax to access `"person.1"`?

I have even changed `DoubleType` to `StringType`, but that didn't work either. Example works fine with just by keeping `person.type` and removing `person.1` in `selectExpr`:

```
val personJsonDf = inputDf.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
val struct = new StructType()
  .add("type", DataTypes.StringType)
  .add("1", DataTypes.DoubleType)
val personNestedDf = personJsonDf
  .select(from_json($"value", struct).as("person"))
val personFlattenedDf = personNestedDf
  .selectExpr("person.type", "person.1")
val consoleOutput = personNestedDf.writeStream
  .outputMode("update")
  .format("console")
  .start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, since `select($"person.1")` should work fine (but you used `selectExpr` which could've confused Spark SQL).

`StructField(1,DoubleType,true)` won't work however since the type should actually be `StringType`.

Let's see...

```
$ cat input.json
{"type":"abc","1":"23.2"}

val input = spark.read.text("input.json")
scala> input.show(false)
+-------------------------+
|value                    |
+-------------------------+
|{"type":"abc","1":"23.2"}|
+-------------------------+

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val struct = new StructType()
  .add("type", DataTypes.StringType)
  .add("1", DataTypes.StringType)
val q = input.select(from_json($"value", struct).as("person"))
scala> q.show
+-----------+
|     person|
+-----------+
|[abc, 23.2]|
+-----------+

val q = input.select(from_json($"value", struct).as("person")).select($"person.1")
scala> q.show
+----+
|   1|
+----+
|23.2|
+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by using  `person.*`

```
+-----+--------+
|type | 1      |
+-----+--------+
|abc  |23.2    |
+-----+--------+
```